# XSLT filePath with document as variable

Tags: variables, xslt, filepath

I try to use a variable in the filePath, but it isn't working:

```
BodyPart filePath="C:\\FileOutEmail\\($vpDocNr).xml" content-type="" content-id="" content-disposition="" multipart-type=""
```

I also tried with the whole path in a variable without results:

```
BodyPart filePath='$bestand'  content-type="" content-id="" content-disposition="" multipart-type=""
```

Is this possible, what is the right syntax?

Comment: Could you tag this question with the programming language you are using. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a (small) example of your XML input and explain what are you trying to do, including the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but supposing your XSLT stylesheet contains:

```
<xsl:variable name="vpDocNr" select="'abc123'"/>
<BodyPart filePath="C:\FileOutEmail\{$vpDocNr}.xml"/>
```

then the result of this part will be:

```
<BodyPart filePath="C:\FileOutEmail\abc123.xml"/>
```